# Gyrocopter doesn't appear after restart a saved game?

Tags: pc, far-cry-4

If I fly back with a Gyrocopter to a Fast Travel location, save the game and restart it later, the Gyrocopter isn't there anymore.

Are there any other things that disappear after restarting my last saved game?

Comment: On a side note I've found that the gyrocopter will be removed after some missions or even just walking too far away,

Answer (score 2):

It appears that animals, vendors, encounters, and vehicles are generally not persistent. Some will reappear at fixed spawn points after a while, like gliders at their launch points.

Answer (score 2):

Fast travel location aren't GTA garages, they don't store you vehicles for you if you leave them there.

There are some fast travel locations which have a respawning buzzer next to them, one example would be be the Ghale Homestead, after you purchase the appropriate upgrade.